# Cómo puedo sumar un numero que esté dentro de un rango definido, en php o js?

Tags: php, javascript, html, function

Quiero que al ingresar un numero en un input text éste se sume automáticamente y el resultado sea devuelto en otro input text:

Es decir:

- si el numero está entre 0-100 se sumará +3
- si el número está entre 101-200 se sumerá +5

Ejm:

- input1 == Ingresar número: "**100**"
- input2 == El total más comisión es: "**103**"

y Así sucesivamente que se pueda sumar cualquier numero que esté dentro de un rango definido.

qué función le daría para que muestre los datos correctamente?

Este es el Código que he intentado hacer mi lógica no está del todo definida ya que no  conozco como establecer rango no sabría si mi if está erróneo, he separado el codigo del formulario que estaba haciendo

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rango de Número</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p><STRONG>Ingresar Precio</STRONG></p>
    <input type="text" name="precio" placeholder="Sub total">


    <p><STRONG>El precio total mas la comision es:</STRONG></p>

        <input type="text" name="Total+Comision" placeholder="Resultado" disabled="disabled">

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function rango(){
        var numero = 0;

        $(".rango").each(function() {
            if (0<=i=<100) {
                sumar numero + i;
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: cualquier lenguaje te sirve pero lo mas importante serías tan amable de agregar lo que haz intentado para de ahí partir y apoyarte saludos y bienvenido

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda soy nuevo en la comunidad :), estuve intentandolo hacer dentro de php con etiqueta script, agregaré el codígo editando la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo con comentarios, espero te ayude.

```js
$(function(){
  
  //Pasar el listener del boton
  $(document).on('click','#bar',function(){
    //Parsear el valor a numero
    var com = parseInt( $( '#foo').val().trim() );
    //Validar si es numero
    if( $.isNumeric( com ) ){
      //Condicionar la comisión
      var comision;
      if( com > 0 && com <= 100 ){
        comision = 3;
      }
      
      else if( com > 100 && com <= 200){
        comision = 5;
      }
      
      else{
        comision = 0;
      }
      //Poner el número al resultado
      $('#poo').val( com + comision );
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Ingresa una comisión</label><br>
<input type="text" id="foo">
<input type="button" value="Nueva comisión" id="bar"><br>
<input type="text" disabled id="poo">
```